# What is the time complexity of this particular code?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I have created a simple program which keeps a count of the elements in an array using an unordered map. I wanted to know the time complexity of the program below.
Is it simply O(n) time?
How much time does the operations done on the unordered map require?
(i.e looking for a key in the map and if it is present incrementing its value by 1 and if not initializing the key by 1)
Is this done in constant time or some logarithmic or linear time?
If not in constant time then please suggest me a better approach.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        int arr[100];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            std::cin >> arr[i];
        std::unordered_map<int, int> dp;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (dp.find(arr[i]) != dp.end())
                dp[arr[i]] ++;
            else
                dp[arr[i]] = 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says, that `std::unordered_map::find()` has a complexity of

> Constant on average, worst case linear in the size of the container.

So you got an average complexity of O(n) and a worst case complexity of O(n^2).

Addendum:
Since you use ints as keys and no custom hash function, I think it is safe to assume O(1) for `find`, since you probably wont get to the worst case.

Comment: can you provide a better approach that takes O(n) in worst case?

Comment: @sanjanamukherjee the answer is correct, but also your approach is ok to keep O(n) complexity to solve, for example, an interview question. It's ok to assume that hash map operations are O(1).